# Proving the function f , which has zero first order parital derivatives, is constant

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Let the function $f: \Bbb R^{2} \to \Bbb R$

The first order derivatives of f are zero.

i.e $f_x(x,y)$ = $f_y(x,y)$ = $0$

How can I prove that $f(x,y)$  is constant for all $(x,y)$

Comment: If $f_x = 0$, then $f(x,y) = g(y)$ for some function $g$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\operatorname{f}_x \equiv 0$ then $\operatorname{f}$ is independent of $x$. (Changing $x$ does not change $\operatorname{f}$.)

If $\operatorname{f}_y \equiv 0$ then $\operatorname{f}$ is independent of $y$. (Changing $y$ does not change $\operatorname{f}$.)

If $\operatorname{f}_x \equiv 0$ and $\operatorname{f}_y \equiv 0$ then $\operatorname{f}$ is independent of both $x$ and $y$.

If $\operatorname{f}$ is independent of both $x$ and $y$ then it must be constant.

Comment: İs that all? So easy. Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

Also consider points $p_1,p_2,...,p_k$ in the function's domain, and what happens when you apply Lagrange's theorem on partial derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

Pick a point $(a,b)$, and pick another point $(c,d)$, both on the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. Assume, without loss of generality, that $a<c$ and $b<d$. Consider $f(x,b)$ as a function of $x$ (of course with $b$ fixed). Then the fundamental theorem calculus (also known as the Newton-Leibniz formula) gives
$$
f(c,b) - f(a,b) = \int_a^c f_x(x,b) \, \mathrm{d} x = 0.
$$
Note that the assumptions of the theorem are trivially satisfied since $f_x$ vanishes identically. Now we consider $f(c,y)$ as a function of $y$. Applying the Newton-Leibniz formula again, we have
$$
f(c,d) - f(c,b) = \int_b^d f_y(c,y) \, \mathrm{d} y = 0.
$$
Finally, we combine the preceding two formulas to conclude
$$
f(c,d) = f(a,b).
$$

Comment: Thank you. This is a good way to solve. Is this proof enough to get successful point from such an exam question?

Comment: Hmm, I am studying by my self on summer holiday for next semmester.. Thank you for helping:) got it well! :)

Comment: Lol! :)) @timur

Comment: @B11b: Seriously though, this answer should be enough on most exams. In a rigorous course, it maybe important to cite the FTC and to explicitly explain how the assumptions of the theorem are satisfied.

Comment: Okay I understand! Thanks:) by the way, I know this is so special question but I wonder, are you Turk? @timur

Comment: I asked because of your name:) sorry for disturbed you:)